# Nested SPM dependency trickery

Tags: swift, objective-c, dependencies, swift-package-manager

`Xcode: 13.3.1`

I've decided to create a chain a dependencies with SPM instead of using compiled libraries and got myself in a situation where the main project throws a bunch of errors. Here is my setup:

**A** (main project, Swift) -> **B** (local, but ideally remote package, xcframework, Swift) -> **C** (remote SPM package with Obj-C source), **D** (remote SPM package with Obj-C source)

**B** compiles with no errors.
Here is what I get when I try to compile **A**:

```
Module 'C' not found, (in B-Swift.h)
Could not build Objective-C module 'B', (in .swiftinterface)
```

Can someone please offer some insight what is happening and possibly a nudge in the right direction to make this setup work?
Found this thread with a similar problem https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/74213, but feels outdated.

Currently exploring: https://forums.swift.org/t/issue-with-third-party-dependencies-inside-a-xcframework-through-spm/41977

**Update**

Converting dependency **C** to `XCFramework` leads to the same dilemma.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I ended up adding C, D as pods to both A, B and making B a SPM for A.